# Replicate groups screen split iOS (when you open an apps folder)

Tags: ios

When you press on a group on the iPhone, the screen splits, and opens up a black background to show contents.  How is this done (structurally, animations, multiple images???)

I figured it is some sort of animation moving the image up or down, but that foesn't account for cutting the image in two.

Thanks for the help, just getting started with animations

Comment: Which app are you talking about?

Comment: I think he's referring to the SpringBoard.

Comment: Just go to any page on you phone and expand a folder. Notice what happens

Comment: Yes, @waf, but then it would have been helpful if you had used the word "folder" anywhere in your question, and if you had said in the question what you just said in the comment. Ask the question carefully and clearly the first time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create 'home screen apps folder'-like button programmatically on iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310612/how-to-create-home-screen-apps-folder-like-button-programmatically-on-ios)

Comment: also [How should I go about recreating the iOS home screen open folder animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14090934/77567)

Comment: I actually voted to close this as a duplicate (rob's 2nd link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this:

https://github.com/jwilling/JWFolders